# Toggle button to call container class flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

hi this is the first time i use a toggle button i try to make the toggle button to call a class container, there are 2 button

[image]

when "folmulir" button is true it called class container 1
when "List data" button is true it called class container 2.

should i make the container in the void so i return it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final List<bool> _selecteddatamaster = <bool>[
  true,
  false,
];

class TestbayToggle extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestbayToggle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TestbayToogleState createState() => TestbayToogleState();
}

class TestbayToogleState extends State<TestbayToggle> {
  List<bool> isSelected = [true, false];
  List<Widget> datamaster = const <Widget>[
    Text('Folmulir'),
    Text('List Data'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 1000,
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[400],
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(8), topRight: Radius.circular(8))),
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 50,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(8), topRight: Radius.circular(8)),
              ),
              child: ToggleButtons(
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _selecteddatamaster.length; i++) {
                      _selecteddatamaster[i] = i == index;
                      if (index == 0) {

                      }
                    }
                  });
                },
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(8), topRight: Radius.circular(8)),
                selectedColor: Colors.black,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                renderBorder: false,
                color: Colors.white,
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: 40.0,
                  minWidth: 100.0,
                ),
                isSelected: _selecteddatamaster,
                children: datamaster ,
              ),
            )
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class Container1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Container1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Container1> createState() => _Container1State();
}

class _Container1State extends State<Container1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
      child: Container(
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8), bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [Text("test1")],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Container2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Container2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
      child: Container(
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8), bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [Text("test2")],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use `Tabbar`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Visibility` widget will serve your case better. Here's an example to demonstrate:

```
bool isSelected = true;   // true by default, becuase first ToggleButton is activated

Visibility(
  child: Container(),     // display container of choice
  visible: isSelected     // will display child if true
);
```